# How to find the error from crash report?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports

i have device logs crash report from iphone 5.how to find the error from my crash report.i am searched most of the link to understand my crash report  but please clarify me where i get crash. i am not got any crash in simulator.

here my crash report...

```
   Incident Identifier: 92DD66DF-03A4-4D63-8501-357BE4951127
CrashReporter Key:   beed3fd2c135f7021a2706a3c7f08e4bce8cec90
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             CR [540]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A5CA78DF-FC16-44F9-AF84-B3E7ABF8B382/CR.app/CR
Identifier:          com.CR.A2
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-01-21 18:57:29.212 +0400
Launch Time:         2015-01-21 18:57:16.384 +0400
OS Version:          iOS 8.1.2 (12B440)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  5

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x26ab549a 0x3426bc86 0x26ab5370 0x27786d7a 0x29f9f242 0x29f9f86a 0x29f9959e 0x2a45df88 0x2a0ea2d2 0x2a258a3e 0x2a259a76 0x2a25b582 0x2a057ada 0xab6e4 0x347cb7b6 0x347d4da6 0x347d5cd2 0x3492ce2c 0x3492cb80)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3489e4f0 0x3489d000 + 5360
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3489e2e4 0x3489d000 + 4836
2   CoreFoundation                  0x26a7b316 0x269af000 + 836374
3   CoreFoundation                  0x26a798bc 0x269af000 + 829628
4   CoreFoundation                  0x269c73bc 0x269af000 + 99260
5   CoreFoundation                  0x269c71ce 0x269af000 + 98766
6   GraphicsServices                0x2ddc50a4 0x2ddbc000 + 37028
7   UIKit                           0x29fd6f9c 0x29f69000 + 450460
8   CR                              0x000bbff6 0xa5000 + 94198
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x347ebaac 0x347ea000 + 6828

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3489e2a0 0x3489d000 + 4768
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x347d79fc 0x347ca000 + 55804
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x347cd20e 0x347ca000 + 12814

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x348b29cc 0x3489d000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492cea8 0x3492c000 + 3752
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492cb80 0x3492c000 + 2944

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x348b29cc 0x3489d000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492cea8 0x3492c000 + 3752
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492cb80 0x3492c000 + 2944

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x348b29cc 0x3489d000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492cea8 0x3492c000 + 3752
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492cb80 0x3492c000 + 2944

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x348b1dfc 0x3489d000 + 85500
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492fd32 0x3492c000 + 15666
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34851904 0x34807000 + 305412
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33b8f9c4 0x33b8f000 + 2500
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ba966c 0x33b8f000 + 108140
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3426bf22 0x34265000 + 28450
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ba6de0 0x33b8f000 + 97760
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ba65a4 0x33b8f000 + 95652
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3426bd5a 0x34265000 + 27994
9   CoreFoundation                  0x26ab5370 0x269af000 + 1074032
10  Foundation                      0x27786d7a 0x276f5000 + 597370
11  UIKit                           0x29f9f242 0x29f69000 + 221762
12  UIKit                           0x29f9f86a 0x29f69000 + 223338
13  UIKit                           0x29f9959e 0x29f69000 + 198046
14  UIKit                           0x2a45df88 0x29f69000 + 5197704
15  UIKit                           0x2a0ea2d2 0x29f69000 + 1577682
16  UIKit                           0x2a258a3e 0x29f69000 + 3078718
17  UIKit                           0x2a259a76 0x29f69000 + 3082870
18  UIKit                           0x2a25b582 0x29f69000 + 3089794
19  UIKit                           0x2a057ada 0x29f69000 + 977626
20  CR                              0x000ab6e4 0xa5000 + 26340
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x347cb7b8 0x347ca000 + 6072
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x347d4da6 0x347ca000 + 44454
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x347d5cd2 0x347ca000 + 48338
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492ce2e 0x3492c000 + 3630
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492cb80 0x3492c000 + 2944

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x348b29cc 0x3489d000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492cea8 0x3492c000 + 3752
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492cb80 0x3492c000 + 2944

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3489e4f0 0x3489d000 + 5360
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3489e2e4 0x3489d000 + 4836
2   CoreFoundation                  0x26a7b316 0x269af000 + 836374
3   CoreFoundation                  0x26a798bc 0x269af000 + 829628
4   CoreFoundation                  0x269c73bc 0x269af000 + 99260
5   CoreFoundation                  0x269c71ce 0x269af000 + 98766
6   CFNetwork                       0x2657c952 0x26500000 + 510290
7   Foundation                      0x277c5b56 0x276f5000 + 854870
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492ee90 0x3492c000 + 11920
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492ee02 0x3492c000 + 11778
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492cb8c 0x3492c000 + 2956

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x348b208c 0x3489d000 + 86156
1   CoreFoundation                  0x26a7fae2 0x269af000 + 854754
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492ee90 0x3492c000 + 11920
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492ee02 0x3492c000 + 11778
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492cb8c 0x3492c000 + 2956

Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000003
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x026d0000      r6: 0x36f68840      r7: 0x026ced78
    r8: 0x146b14a0    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x14655bf0     r11: 0x146b14c4
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x026ced6c      lr: 0x3492fd37      pc: 0x348b1dfc
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Thank in advance..

Comment: You need to symbolicate it. There is an exception in a background thread. Nothing else can be said at this point.

Comment: thank you..but i trying my same code in xib is running with out crash.. in storyboard i got crash

Answer (score 0):

You may dispatch some UI operation in subthread. Make sure operate UI only in main thread. Symbolicating the Crash Report to get more details.

```c
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x348b1dfc 0x3489d000 + 85500
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492fd32 0x3492c000 + 15666
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34851904 0x34807000 + 305412
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33b8f9c4 0x33b8f000 + 2500
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ba966c 0x33b8f000 + 108140
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3426bf22 0x34265000 + 28450
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ba6de0 0x33b8f000 + 97760
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33ba65a4 0x33b8f000 + 95652
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3426bd5a 0x34265000 + 27994
9   CoreFoundation                  0x26ab5370 0x269af000 + 1074032
10  Foundation                      0x27786d7a 0x276f5000 + 597370
11  UIKit                           0x29f9f242 0x29f69000 + 221762
12  UIKit                           0x29f9f86a 0x29f69000 + 223338
13  UIKit                           0x29f9959e 0x29f69000 + 198046
14  UIKit                           0x2a45df88 0x29f69000 + 5197704
15  UIKit                           0x2a0ea2d2 0x29f69000 + 1577682
16  UIKit                           0x2a258a3e 0x29f69000 + 3078718
17  UIKit                           0x2a259a76 0x29f69000 + 3082870
18  UIKit                           0x2a25b582 0x29f69000 + 3089794
19  UIKit                           0x2a057ada 0x29f69000 + 977626
20  CR                              0x000ab6e4 0xa5000 + 26340 // symbol and check this line
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x347cb7b8 0x347ca000 + 6072
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x347d4da6 0x347ca000 + 44454
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x347d5cd2 0x347ca000 + 48338
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492ce2e 0x3492c000 + 3630
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3492cb80 0x3492c000 + 2944
```